# Importing all .dpt files in a folder, combine the second columns and save as .xlsx

Tags: import

I have a folder of 457 .dpt files, which I would like to import in to Mathematica, extract the second column, and combine all 457 into one array, to then save as a .xlsx file. I just can't get the loop right, I've tried For and Do. Also I get the impression that Mathematica isn't great at appending columns so I tried to append them as rows then transpose at the end.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
Clear["Global'*"];

SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\...blahblah...\\TPP 13 Dec 17 (DPT Files)"];

files = FileNames[]; (*gives a list of the 457 filenames*)

out={};

For[i = 0, i < 457, i++,

    data = Import[files[[i]]]

    col = data[[All, 2]] (*Extracts second column*)

    AppendTo[out, {col}]

 ]

outputfile=Transpose[out]

Export["allthedatainonefile.xlsx",outputfile]
```

Comment: Look at the syntax for [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).  You could do `out = Table[ Import[ file][[All,2]], {file, files}]`

Comment: or `Map` :  `Export["path",Import[#][[All,2]]&/@files];`

Comment: @george2079 should your code replace everything I have? Or just what's in the for loop?

Comment: @JasonB What exact section of my code is your line supposed to replace? I'm not a good programmer, I need this spoon-fed to me I'm afraid.

Comment: See the paste here, https://pastebin.com/raw/fvn1fbH4.  Any time you find yourself using a `For` loop, and appending to a list at each step, there is usually a better, more *Mathematica* way to do it.  I included a longer version which is commented out.

Comment: that one line replaces everything after the `files=` line.  (Except I forgot to transpose, so `Export["path",Transpose[Import[#][[All,2]]&/@files]];` )